# How to prevent manual assignment of an IP of VLAN/subnet A when connected to a VLAN/subnet B?

Tags: cisco, dhcp

I'm configuring a Cisco router C1111-8p using IOS XE 16.8 with 3 VLANs.

- VLAN **1**: native/management 192.168.**0**.0/24
- VLAN **10** : 192.168.**10**.0/24
- VLAN **20** : 192.168.**20**.0/24

I haven't set ACLs up yet but basically:

- I'd like to block everything but 2ports from outside and these 2 ports will be connected to VLAN 10 only.
- VLAN 10,20 can communicate to each other.
- Management/Native VLAN 1: Nobody should be able to access it but the Wireless AP for eap-tls management and Radius server.

**Questions:**

- Connected to VLAN10, either from `SSID10` or the `GigabitEthernet 0/1/2`. Why can I manually define my IP as a VLAN1 or VLAN10's IP?
- Why can I literally obtain legally a different VLAN/subnet's IP than the one I'm connected to?

Wanting inter-VLANs communication doesn't mean I want my device be able to obtain an IP from a different VLAN/subnet.

In that case, there is a huge security weakness because someone in my network can obtain a management IP.

**My config:**

```
# Setup ISP internet connection
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet 0/0/0
description WAN
ip address 219.*.*.* 255.255.255.252
ip nat outside
no shutdown
end
conf t
ip nat inside source list NAT interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 219.*.*.*
ip dns server
ip domain-lookup
ip name-server 221.110.33.164 221.110.33.132
end

# Set DHCP pools
configure terminal
service dhcp
# Native pool
ip dhcp pool vlanNativePool
network 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.0.1
exit
# VLAN 10 pool
ip dhcp pool vlan10Pool
network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.10.1
dns-server 221.110.33.164 221.110.33.132
# VLAN 20 pool
ip dhcp pool vlan20Pool
network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
default-router 192.168.20.1
dns-server 221.110.33.164 221.110.33.132
end

#NAT
configure terminal
ip access-list standard NAT
permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
end

#Setup the trunk port between the switch and the WAP
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1/0
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk native vlan 1
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1,10,20
switchport nonegotiate
no shutdown
end

#Setup the port VLAN 1 native for the Radius/squid server
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1/6
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 1
no shutdown
exit
#Setup the port VLAN 1 for management
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1/7
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 1
no shutdown
end

# Setup the switch port for direct VLAN access
configure terminal
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1/2
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 10
no shutdown
exit
interface GigabitEthernet 0/1/3
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 20
no shutdown
exit

# Configure VLANs
ip routing
configure terminal
# VLAN 1 DEFAULT NATIVE
vlan 1
interface vlan 1
ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
exit
# VLAN 10
vlan 10
no shutdown
interface vlan 10
ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
no shutdown
exit
# VLAN 20
vlan 20
no shutdown
interface vlan 20
ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
no shutdown
end
```

Comment: i am not clear what you are asking? are you expecting to do intervlan Routing? between vlans?

Comment: I'm expecting that a computer connected to a switch port VLAN10 can't obtain a VLAN1's ip if it sets it up manually in his OS' settings.

Comment: do you configure dhcp relay agent?

Comment: I don't think so, my config is written in my question.

Comment: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ace/v3-00_A2/configuration/rtg_brdg/guide/rtbrgdgd/dhcp.pdf you can see configurations

Comment: You don't give model or software version, so I have to ask, does the router have proxy ARP enabled?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if proxy ARP is enabled or not. I'm using **C1111-8p** with **IOS XE 16.8**.

Comment: `show running-config` doesn't show any proxy ARP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you limit the administrative privileges on a host, you cannot prevent a user/admin to set any local IP address they like.

Usually, manually configuring an IP address from another VLAN/subnet renders a host deaf and dumb since no other node in its actual VLAN uses that IP subnet. Using an IP address from a specific subnet doesn't make the host a member of the required VLAN.

Using DHCP, the server won't assign any address from another subnet. Some switches support enforcing DHCP configuration by using strict IP/MAC binding with DHCP snooping - a node cannot use any other IP address than the one assigned by DHCP.

Basically, IP subnet are mapped to VLANs and you cannot simply choose a VLAN by changing your IP address.

Entering a specific VLAN other than your native VLAN (=the untagged VLAN on your switch port) requires the host to tag frames and the switch to accept those frames. Common best practice is to not accept tagged frames on a host port (standard for an *access port* on Cisco equipment).

Comment: *Usually, manually configuring an IP address from another VLAN/subnet renders a host deaf and dumb...* True, in the case where proxy ARP is disabled. However depending on platform and software version proxy ARP may be enabled by default and allow this traffic to leak.

Comment: That's true, I tried to ping other VLANs and internet, I couldn't. Actually I access VLANs from wireless.